# Partial Views in .net core vs .Net Framework

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller

Good morning, I am migrating an application from .net framework to .net Core.
and I can't find a way to pass the controller to partial view.
In my Framework app, call to PartialView
`Html.RenderAction("_IndexRaceDetail", "RaceDetails", new { IdRace = Model.Id })`
where "RaceDetails" is the name controller, but in .net core, call the partial view `@await Html.PartialAsync("../Shared/_Races")` or using helpers `<partial name="nameViewPartial" />` but and I don't know how to pass the name of the partial view controller as a parameter since it always uses the main view controller.
If anyone knows the way, I will appreciate the information.

Comment: Partial Views in ASP.NET Core do not have Controller actions behind them like that. Perhaps View Components can accomplish what you need https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: Hi, thanks very much. 
this is what I was needing, many things changed from framework to core and migrations are complicated, thank you very much, greetings